# How to avoid White line between img and td bottom?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have made a banner **img** in a **td** element. I have included a reset script to remove all margins, paddings and spaces everywhere.

```
<td><img /></td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/227JH/

But there still is being showed a blank line. How can I remove the blank line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `vertical-align` property for an `img` element is `baseline`.

Changing it to `top`, `middle` or `bottom` fixes the issue.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/8R65r/)

```
td img {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also add `display:block` to the `img` element.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/8R65r/1/)

```
td img {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: @Paedow You're welcome. Glad that's what you were looking for -- I just took a random guess ;) And, that edit somehow got rejected.. I don't know why. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3584014 .. I would have approved it.

Comment: maybe someone else edited it a few seconds before me